# WhatsApp not opening on Macbook (OSX 12.7.2)

Tags: whatsapp.app

I have WhatsApp on my iPhone and Macbook. WhatsApp has suddenly stopped opening on my MacBook.  I've restarted OSX but it doesn't help. WhatsApp starts to load but stalls on the page where it usually loads.  This page stays white and nothing more happens (see attached picture).  [image]

If I delete and reinstall will I lose contacts, message threads etc?

Comment: delete and re-sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete and re-instal you will not loose your contacts

It might just have lost the sync to your phone so just follow the procedure to re-sync the Mac to your phone

Comment: Yes!  I deleted, reinstalled and re-synched and it's all good.  Thank you!  The new version I have now looks different to the old... so maybe there has been an important update I missed...?

Answer (score 1):

First, see if clearing the Saved State helps, rather than going immediately for a reinstall - which will leave all ancillary files behind anyway & is usually pointless unless you clean those too.
I don't know how WhatsApp saves or restores your conversations through a clean install, so I can't suggest how to work around that.

Quit the app.
Hold  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   & click it in the Dock to launch.

This will discard just the last running state, without clearing any other data.

Comment: Thanks.  I deleted, reinstalled and re-synched and it's all good.